# Using a second app in Django

Tags: python, django

I am a django novice. I am attempting to use a 3rd-party app with my own app for the very first time.

I'm trying to use the following simple authentication app:
https://github.com/mikl/django-password-required

My problem is that I don't understand what combination of imports I need in order to make use of this. My file hierarchy is as follows.

```
+ MyName
      + MyName
              - urls.py
              - views.py
              - settings.py
              - ... 
      + password_required
              - decorators.py
              - views.py
              - ... 
      - Manage.py
```

Lets assume I have a view called home in MyApp/MyApp/views.py. `r'^$'` maps to home and this works fine without any password protection. However as soon as I add the `@password_required` above `def home(request):`, trouble start.

password_required is in `installed_apps` within settings.py. When I try to `import password_required.views` within urls.py, I get

> The included urlconf '<function login at 0x7f41asdvbas7c950\>' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

I have tried syncdb and resetting my server.

I'm not married to using this app, however I convinced that I will face this again if I don't learn to use multiple apps. Thank you ahead of time.

--EDIT--

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

from MyName import views
import password_required.views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^password_required/$', include(password_required.views.login)),    
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from password_required.decorators import password_required

@password_required
def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World!')
```

Comment: Show your `urls.py`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `include()` function to attach the single view to the url:

```
url(r'^password_required/$', password_required.views.login),
```

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you put quotes around 'password_required.views.login'?

Comment: No, in this case in will be the same.  The only difference is if you around the `password_required.views.login` with quotes then you can delete the `import password_required.views` line.  Django will automatically import the module by the name.